# What does this '.src' do here in next js?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

Here I'm setting background image in Next js. I've found a solution here to add `.src` at the end like this

```
import bgImg from '../public/images/Error/BG.png';

 <Layout style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bgImg.src})`}}> </Layout>
```

I don't know what the `src` in `bgImg.src` do?.
Please explain.

Comment: The ".src" appended to "bgImg" is referring to the source of the image. Specifically, it is pointing to the path of the image file. This is necessary when using the "backgroundImage" property in the Layout component, as it requires a valid URL or file path in order to set a background image.

Comment: so its equal to adding relative path? If I dont add relative path then it should have '.src' right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you console.log(bgImg)

You will find the output syntax to be like:

```
 bgImg: {
    src: '...',
    height: 1028,
    width: 1013,
    blurDataURL: '...'      
  }
```

So your are basically accessing image source object value with dot notation.

Comment: Cool. I didnt find anything related to this in docs.

Comment: @Sins97 that's probably because it's handled by a webpack loader, Next doesn't do the bundling

Comment: Can you share me some resources relating to those because I need to learn about those things

Comment: Just go googling around your requirements, that's how I learnt

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, when you import a file, the file is interpreted as a module, which can contain one or more exports. These exports can be variables, functions, classes, or objects that can be used by other parts of your application.

In this case, the line import bgImg from '../public/images/Error/BG.png'; is importing the image file located at the specified path, and the imported value is being assigned to the variable bgImg.

The .src property is a property of the imported image file that contains the URL of the file. It's often used to set the src attribute of an img element in HTML, so that the image can be displayed on the page. In this case, it is being used to set the backgroundImage property of the Layout component which is being passed a string that contains the URL of the image file.

So the bgImg.src is returning the path of the imported image file, which is being used as the value of the backgroundImage property, so that the image can be displayed as background of the layout component.

Comment: Cool. I didnt find anything related to this in docs.

Comment: check i have updated the answer hope it helps you understand now